# Cannot create more then two c3js graphs on a page

Tags: html, d3.js, c3.js

We are using the following code (generated by php but finally this is on client side)

```
c3.generate({'bindto':'#b65d3422__salestaffcommunication_xepan_base_view_chart_chart','data':{'keys':{'x':'name','value':['Email','Call','Meeting']},'groups':[['Email','Call','Meeting']],'json':[],'type':'bar'},'axis':{'x':{'type':'category'},'rotated':true},'onrendered':function(ev,ui){$(".widget-grid").masonry({'itemSelector':'.widget'})}});
c3.generate({'bindto':'#f67e14d8__t_masscommunication_xepan_base_view_chart_chart','data':{'keys':{'x':'name','value':['Newsletter','TeleMarketing']},'groups':[['Newsletter','TeleMarketing']],'json':[],'type':'bar'},'axis':{'x':{'type':'category'},'rotated':true},'onrendered':function(ev,ui){$(".widget-grid").masonry({'itemSelector':'.widget'})}});
c3.generate({'bindto':'#517df254__ableworkforce_xepan_base_view_chart_chart','data':{'columns':[['present',11.111111111111]],'type':'gauge'},'color':{'pattern':['#FF0000','#F97600','#F6C600','#60B044'],'threshold':{'values':[30,60,90,100]}},'onrendered':function(ev,ui){$(".widget-grid").masonry({'itemSelector':'.widget'})}});
```

And last graph is not drawn. showing

```
SyntaxError (DOM Exception 12): The string did not match the expected pattern.
```

However, I can run ANY two and it works fine. that means all code is perfect but once second one is drawn ( no matter in which order). Third one doesn't draws.

Is it any known bug, or any workaround known.

Using v0.4.11 of c3 from c3js.org

Here is my jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/2yy2mjaf/1/

Thank you.

Comment: Never Mind Guys !!!

Was issue of div id starting from number. 
I prepended an alphabet and everything started working.

leaving answer for others.

Comment: Really, mate? Are you completely pretending that my answer was not there? Just look at the timestamp of my answer and the timestamp of your comment... You're not getting much help at SO with this behaviour.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado, Oops, sorry. I really didn't refreshed the page and I do appreciate your efforts. Thank you in any case :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IDs **cannot** start with a number, which is the case of your third ID.

The simple solution is just adding a letter to it:

```
'bindto':'#a517df254_ //just put an "a" before the number here
```

Here is your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7dkLdg32/